# JW Player How to take out the screen area above the control bar?

Tags: javascript, flash, jwplayer

Sorry if it is wrong section to post this. I want use JW player as an audio player. So I want to take it out the area above control bar which display thumbnails because I only want control bar to display. If that's only one song, i can just change the height of the JW player but now what I want is with playlist. So If i change the height of the JW player, the bottom playlist is screwed up. I attached the image to make it clear.

[image]

Playlist Become like this when I change the height of the JW player

[image]

Comment: Because JW player can use as both video player or audio player

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I have put together using examples from JWPlayer's site:

```
jwplayer('video').setup({
    width: '480',
    height: '24',
    'playlist': [{
        'file': '/Nebraska.mp3',
        'title': 'Nebraska - Bruce Springsteen'
    }, {
        'file': '/Atlantic_City.mp3',
        'title': 'Atlantic City - Bruce Springsteen'
    }],
    modes: [
        { type: "html5" },
        { type: "flash", src: "/mediaplayer/player.swf" },
        { type: "download" }
    ],
    'playlist.position': 'top',
    'playlist.size': '120',
    'controlbar': 'top'
});
```

The important things to note in my example are:

1. The height of the player. This should be `24px`, because `24px` is the height of the control bar.
2. The `playlist.position` and `controlbar` properties. These should both be set to the same thing. I have set them both to `top`; this will position the playlist above the player just like your example.
3. The `playlist.size` property. Each playlist item has a height of `60px`, therefore to avoid scrollbars and playlist item stretching this property should only be in multiples of `60`, beginning at `60`. You could probably calculate this to show only the number of playlist items required, and then have the user scroll to see the rest.

The final result I got looks like this:

[image: JWPlayer Audio]